# Get layout frame of NSView (i.e. ibLayoutInset)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface, interface-builder, nsview

I'm working on an Interface Builder-type app for interface design. I would like to be able to align NSView's along their layout frames. Is there a way to access the ibLayoutInset property from my code?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Interface Builder Kit's NSView additions](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/NSViewIBAdditions_Reference/Reference/Reference.html). Is that what you're looking for?